# Using Custom Figure Settings in Future Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've customized a 2D plot and I'd like to reuse the settings of the axes, labels, font sizes, etc. in future plots.  For example, I've set the following settings for this particular plot, and I'd like to be able to somehow save them as a "style" for use in future figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2, 2)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# text specific to this plot, but attributes common to all
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = x^2$', linewidth=2)
ax.set_xlabel('$x$', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('$y$', fontsize=20)
ax.set_title('Graph of $y = x^2$', fontsize=20)

# common to all plots
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('grey')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('grey')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('grey')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('grey')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.tick_params(colors='grey')

plt.show()
```

In particular, for the first four lines under `# text specific...` the strings in the functions are specific to this figure, but the attributes like `linewidth=2` I'd like future plots to share.  The lines under `# common to all plots` are attributes I'd like all future figures to share.  Is there a way I can save this as a "style" for ease of use, perhaps as some argument to `plt.figure()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib allows to use styles in the sense of predefined parameters for many of the plot's settings.

You'll find a good introduction and sample cases in the [matplotlib customization article](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

One option is to create your own style file. 
The directory matplotlib looks for style files is can be found via `print matplotlib.get_configdir()`. In this folder create a subfolder called `stylelib`, if it isn't already present. 
You'd then create a file called `mystyle.mplstyle` inside. 
The contents of this file in your case would be

```
### MATPLOTLIBRC FORMAT
lines.linewidth   : 2     # line width in points
axes.edgecolor      : grey   # axes edge color
axes.titlesize      : 20   # fontsize of the axes title
axes.labelsize      : 20  # fontsize of the x any y labels
axes.labelcolor     : grey
axes.spines.left   : True   # display axis spines
axes.spines.bottom : True
axes.spines.top    : False
axes.spines.right  : False
xtick.top            : False   # draw ticks on the top side
xtick.bottom         : True   # draw ticks on the bottom side
xtick.color          : grey      # color of the tick labels
ytick.left           : True   # draw ticks on the left side
ytick.right          : False  # draw ticks on the right side
ytick.color          : grey      # color of the tick labels
legend.loc           : best
```

In the list you obtain via `print plt.style.available` you should now find an entry `mystyle`.
Your python script can then read this style in via `plt.style.use('mystyle')`.
And your plotting script can be reduced to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('mystyle')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x=range(8)
y=[1,5,4,3,2,7,4,5]

ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = x^2$') 
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax.set_title('Graph of $y = x^2$')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Note that you still need to call `ax.legend()` to obtain a legend.

In case something is not working as expected, ask a specific and more narrow question about it.

Comment: @ImportanceoOfBeingErnest Thanks for the great writeup.  The only issue is that the ticks on the top and right axes are still visible.  Any idea how to get rid of these?

Comment: I tested it with matplotlib 2.0 and it worked fine. Which version are you using? Did you exactly copy the sniplets from my answer? Can you show an image of how it looks (possibly upload it to imgur.com or so)?

Comment: Nevermind, I upgraded matplotlib to 2.0.0 and it looks good.  Thanks again!

Comment: That is indeed one possible solution. ;-)